# Theorem 16 , Chapter 5 of Northcott 's, Finite Free Resolutions: p.grade

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. **D.G. Northcott**'s, *Finite Free Resolutions*, has:
[image]

and in **Theorem 16** of **Chapter 5** proves that: 
$p.grade(I,M) = p.grade(P,M)$ for some prime ideal $P$ containing $I$ .

> **Question.** Let $I$ be a *finitely generated ideal*. Can one claim that there is a *finitely generated* prime ideal $P$ containing $I$ such that $p.grade(I,M) = p.grade(P,M)$?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need P finitely generated ?, what for ? The aim of Northcott's theory of grade is to avoid finiteness of ideal-generators (the ground ring is any commutative ring, not necessary Noetherian ).

Comment: yes the ring is  not necessary Noetherian, in the Question too. but it can have finitely generated ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for an ideal may be finitely generated without being contained in *any* finitely generated prime ideal. For example, the zero ideal in a non-noetherian zero-dimensional local ring has this property.